# Silverlight & Dynamics CRM 2011 - Application fails when checking date field

Tags: c#, silverlight, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a silverlight application which is going in one of my CRM dashboards, it needs to check whether or not a specified date is equal to the date on the record, it also needs to check whether or not one of the fields on the record is an empty string:

```
private void SearchContacts(Nullable<DateTime> date)
{
    try
    {
         DateTime UpdatedTime = date ?? DateTime.Now;
         DataServiceQuery<myentity> query = (DataServiceQuery<myentity>)_context.myentitySet.AddQueryOption("$filter", "((my_ForMonthEnding eq '" + UpdatedTime.ToString() + "') and (my_ActionDetails eq ''))");
         query.BeginExecute(OnMyEntitySearchComplete, query);
    }
    catch (SystemException ex)
    {
         _syncContext.Send(new SendOrPostCallback(showErrorDetails), ex);
    }
}
```

This code generates the following error:

> Operator 'eq' incompatible with operand types 'System.Nullable'

This seems odd to me as I'm casting the nullable DateTime to a standard DateTime, so I must be missing something.  Can someone please explain what it is In eed to do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never worked with Silverlight or DataServiceQuery before so this may be a stab in the dark, but `my_ForMonthEnding`  would be a `nullable` type.  Can you try changing it to `my_ForMonthEnding.Value`?

### Edit 1

Ok, so it looks like you're generating an OData URL using the DataServiceQuery.  Here is an example Filter that I created using LinqPad:

```
$filter=(CreatedOn eq datetime'2012-11-14T11:18:38.4769698-05:00') and (my_name eq '')
```

CreatedOn is a `DateTime?`, and this works just fine.  Can you try adding datetime in front of your string date and removing your outside parenthesis?

```
        DataServiceQuery<myentity> query = (DataServiceQuery<myentity>)_context.myentitySet
            .AddQueryOption("$filter", "(my_ForMonthEnding eq datetime'" + UpdatedTime.ToString() + "') and (my_ActionDetails eq '')");
        query.BeginExecute(OnMyEntitySearchComplete, query);
```

Comment: Hi, cheers for the reply, if I do what you suggest I get "or operator expected at position 25" error.

Comment: Hi thanks for helping out again, the code above gives the following error: "Unrecognised EDM.datetime literal", any idea what this means?

Answer (score 1):

This is the query I used which worked:

```
DataServiceQuery<myentity> query = (DataServiceQuery<myentity>)_context.myEntitySet.Where(c => c.my_ForMonthEnding == date && c.my_ActionDetails.Equals(null));
                query.BeginExecute(OnContactSearchComplete, query);
```